# Why cant i install any desktop environments in the ubuntu server 18.04.1? (unable to locate package kubuntu-desktop)

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-environments

I tried to look it up on YouTube, i tried `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`, but it just does not work! It says "unable to locate package kubuntu-desktop". And yes, i want to install Kubuntu desktop. Please help me!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Standard Ubuntu only enables the 'main' repository, which for 18.04 only has the GNOME desktop.  You must enable the 'universe' first to load any Ubuntu flavor DEsktop (inc. KDE/Kubuntu's).  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for more details on repistorities.

Comment: You may want command line versions if just server. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine But good to review link above to understand repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Standard Ubuntu only enables the `main` repository, which for 18.04 only has the GNOME desktop. You must enable the `universe` first to load any Ubuntu flavor Desktop Environment (inc. KDE/Kubuntu's).

For details on Repositories, you can look at
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

You can add it via

- Ubuntu Software (see first link)
- commands (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine)

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe
  ```
- adding `universe` to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` using your favorite editor (you'll need `sudo` to elevate your rights to write to that file)

After this, you can `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`.